# Easiest way to put something into orbit

Tags: orbit

What is the easiest (and cheapest) way to launch a small object into orbit? I know this is not anywhere near a simple task, but I want to put something into orbit for a small amount of money.

Thanks!
Holden

Comment: [Clyde Tombaugh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clyde_Tombaugh) made it all the way out of the solar system for free - ok, only [some of his ashes](http://www.jhuapl.edu/newscenter/pressreleases/2006/060203_image1.asp). The way to make something happen without paying for it is to make it part of someone else's mission. Look for a contest, a sponsor, a rich relative...

Answer (score 1):

The Easiest and cheapest way would probably be as a secondary payload on a already scheduled launch as a cubesat or micro sat or pico sat.

Also Cheapest here is a very misleading term as most cubesat launches are in the tens and hundred of thousands of dollars.  There are companies that are trying to bring the price down like http://www.interorbital.com/ and https://www.rocketlabusa.com/ but they are still year(s) away from launching orbital missions.